# Date(); returning same time even with an event in php

Tags: php, date

is there another way to do it than this? because both $timestart and $timestop give me the same result even tho theres an event between both.

```
<?php 
$timestart = strtotime(date('H:i:s', time()));

if(isset($_POST['choix186']) ){
    $timestop = strtotime(date('H:i:s', time()));
    $duree = $timestop - $timestart;
    }

print $duree"; 
?>
```

Comment: You assign the same values to $timestart and $timestop. What values do you want to have at those two variables?

Comment: What do you expect? The only thing you have between them is an `isset()` call, which takes a tiny fraction of a millisecond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the "standard" timer script is this one:

Example #1 Timing script execution with microtime()

```
$time_start = microtime_float();

// Sleep for a while
usleep(100);

$time_end = microtime_float();
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "Did nothing in $time seconds\n";
?>
```

Example #2 Timing script execution in PHP 5

```
<?php
$time_start = microtime(true);

// Sleep for a while
usleep(100);

$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "Did nothing in $time seconds\n";
?>
```

Example #3 microtime() and REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT (as of PHP 5.4.0)

```
<?php
// Randomize sleeping time
usleep(mt_rand(100, 10000));

// As of PHP 5.4.0, REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT is available in the $_SERVER superglobal array.
// It contains the timestamp of the start of the request with microsecond precision.
$time = microtime(true) - $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"];

echo "Did nothing in $time seconds\n";
?>
```

source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

nothing to add, manual knows all

Comment: how do you convert it in seconds or minutes?

Comment: just apply the appropriate math